# Usb camera selection on openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, webcam

I am trying to use my usb connected webcam in my opencv project.

when I use;

```
 cvCreateCameraCapture(0); //integrated web cam
```

opencv selects my integrated webcam.

when i use;

```
cvCreateCameraCapture(1); //for usb web cam
```

It selects nothing. It also does not work for any other parameters.

I tried to disabling and uninstalling my integrated web cam. It also does not work for neither of above.

Neither of them does not give any error. It simply does not display the capture.

I correctly installed usb web cam to my computer.

I use 32 bits windows 7 and visual studio 2010

Thanks, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody is complaining about capture problems on windows. if you search SO for opencv webcam, you'll find tons of fellow programmers with the same problem.

The good news is that the issue was found by somenone just yesterday. it's a bug in opencv:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1470

(The solution was't yet confirmed as reliable, but you can test it)

Comment: Simple COM initialization.  Its no surprise, the cap_dshow.cpp code is horrendous.